# Activerecord .find datetime by month

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get all records which have a datetime field (not created at) in a given month

Eg

```
month = 1
@events_this_month = Events.find :all, :conditions => {:date.month => month}
```

Obviously not the way to do it (symbol isn't a date object!) but I hope it gives you an idea of what I'm hoping for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a gem just for this reason called [by_star](http://github.com/radar/by_star), You can find events for a given month using this syntax:

```
Event.by_month(2)
```

That code would get you all the events for the 2nd month of the yeah. It also does month names and takes Date and Time objects.

Should be perfect for your needs.

A little additional tip: your model classes should be singularized. That's the convention in Rails.

Comment: Thanks will fix (camping by the way but I assume it still applies!)

Comment: Sorry to push this again after giving you the tick - this is not co-operating with camping because of Time.zone.now.year... this is rails centric I'm afraid. . .

Comment: @minikomi: It only needs `Time.zone` to be set. Just set `Time.zone = 'Sydney'` for example in your application.